# How to update grub after windows 10 install?

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, windows-10, boot-repair

I recently updated to windows 10.

When I boot to windows from grub I get the error: "Windows Failed to Start A Recent Hardware or Software Change Might Be The Cause."

Changing the name in /boot/grub/grib.config to "windows 10" from "windows 7" didn't fix it.

The only way to boot to windows is to switch to bios, and manually boot to the drive that windows is on. This is inconvenient and I would like to know how to update grub to reflect the change to windows 10.

I tried Ubuntu Boot repair, but it again set my boot option to "windows 7."

I'm not sure which logs to look at.

Comment: Windows 7 is usually BIOS mode and Windows 10 is usually UEFI mode. Ubuntu's GRUB will only boot Windows that is the same mode as Ubuntu. First confirm that that Windows and Ubuntu boot in the same mode. - https://itsfoss.com/check-uefi-or-bios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot to Ubuntu and mount the Windows drive (if you're using UEFI, mount the EFI partition too as root.)

Use the command:

```
sudo os-prober
```

and try updating the GRUB config using the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will automatically detect the changes and you can try booting again.
Also, don't update GRUB manually from grub.cfg. There could be unintended side effects. Next time if you want to edit the config, use:

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

GRUB Customizer can help rename, add, delete and edit your entries. It's a good tool and you can use it on Ubuntu.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks!